# Can't import 'baconjs' into Angular 2 service

Tags: angular, systemjs, bacon.js, angular-cli

I am using angular-cli to create a new Angular 2 project. I am trying to add the 'baconjs' npm project, but having no success.

I am following the instructions here: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/3rd-party-libs

The npm and typings installs work find. Changing the angular-cli-build.js file causes 'vendor/baconjs/dist/Bacon.js' to be installed in the dist/ directory. However, attempting `import * as foo from 'baconjs'` results in this error:

```
Cannot find module 'baconjs'.
```

I have also tried `...from 'baconjs/Bacon'` and `...from 'baconjs/Bacon.js'`. I have tried many different incantations in my system-config.ts. This is my current version:

```
const map: any = {
  'baconjs': 'vendor/baconjs/dist'
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'baconjs': { main: 'Bacon', defaultExtension: 'js' }
};
```

I have tried all of the different values for the 'format' field. I have tried with and without the defaultExtension. I've tried lots of stuff. No dice.

Mysteriously, `System.import('baconjs/Bacon.js')` seems to work just fine when placed at the top of the very same file with the bad import. So all of that systemjs config is doing *something*.

Hmm, looks like similar questions are asked all over the place. Oh well. Putting it on the record....

Answer (score 0):

Okay, here is what worked for me after reading a lot of docs and playing around a lot. These are *almost* the same as the instructions for underscore on the angular wiki, but with one important change.

```
npm install baconjs --save
typings install baconjs --save --global
```

Change the angular-cli-build and system-config files as described, then in the typescript file for your service file:

```
/// <reference path="../../../../../../typings/globals/baconjs/index.d.ts" />
import * as Bacon from 'baconjs';
```

The difference is the import line, as opposed to the `declare var _;` in the wiki. It is also important that the `/// <reference ...` line be the very first line in the file.